# include website in latex presentation

Tags: beamer

is it possible to somehow insert a website in a latex beamer presentation, so I can interact with it? if so, would it work with web 2.0 sites? could i include a google slides presentation inside a latex beamer presentation?

Comment: Short answer: this is (virtually) impossible. It is much easier to just open a separate web browser and switch to it during your presentation when needed. You can stay in full-screen mode in both the LaTeX pdf and the browser and switch with alt-tab (or ⌘-tab on Mac) for a smooth transition.

Comment: Or you can have a link in the pdf, which opens the browser. But if the goal is to embed another set of slides, maybe there are other ways? Can google slides be saved as pdf? Than they can easily be added to a beamer presentation.

Comment: how would you include this exported pdf document?

Comment: If you want someone to notify about your answer, use an @ before their name. That way you won't have to wait for them to come back to this page by chance.

Comment: If you want to include whole pages, `pdfpages` is your package. If you want them to take only part of your slide, than `includegraphics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the slides as `.pdf`, than you can include them in your presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

    {
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=} 
        \includepdf[pages=1-2]{document.pdf}    
    }

    \begin{frame}
        efg
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]